# homotopy equivalence induces homotopy equivalence of Hom complexes?

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $f\colon A\to B$ be a homotopy equivalence of chain complexes
(with $g$ the weak inverse and chain homotopies 
$\phi\colon {\rm id}_D\to f\circ g$ and 
$\psi\colon g\circ f\to{\rm id}_C$).
Then the associated chain map between Hom-complexes
$$
f_\ast\colon\mathcal{H}om(X,A)\to\mathcal{H}om(X,B)
$$
is again a homotopy equivalence with weak inverse $g_\ast$ and chain homotopies 
$\phi_\ast$ and $\psi_\ast$.

I think this is also true for a general dg-category $\mathcal{C}$,
namely if $f\colon A\to B$ is a homotopy equivalence 
inducing isomorphism in the homotopy category, 
then the associated chain map 
$$
f_\ast\colon\mathcal{H}om_{\mathcal{C}}(X,A)\to\mathcal{H}om_{\mathcal{C}}(X,B)
$$
is a homotopy equivalence. 
Now, all the above constructions $f_\ast$, $g_\ast$, $\phi_\ast$ and $\psi_\ast$ 
still exist. The problem is to show that $\phi_\ast$ and $\psi_\ast$ are chain homotopies.

Note that, in the case of chain complexes, 
for $h$ an element of $\mathcal{H}om(X,A)$, 
we have
\begin{align}
(\partial\circ\phi_\ast+\phi_\ast\circ\partial)(h)
&= \partial(\phi\circ h) +\phi\circ(\partial (h)) \\
&= \partial^D\circ\phi\circ h - (-1)^{1+|h|}\phi\circ h\circ\partial^X \\
&\qquad + \phi\circ\partial^C\circ h - (-1)^{|h|}\phi\circ h\circ\partial^X \\
&= (\partial^D\circ\phi + \phi\circ\partial^C)\circ h \\
&= (g\circ f - {\rm id}_C)\circ h \\
&= (g_\ast\circ f_\ast -{\rm id})(h).
\end{align}
Hence $\phi_\ast$ is a chain homotopy. 
Similar for $\psi_\ast$.

My question is: 
**How to show $\phi_\ast$ is a chain homotopy in general dg-category $\mathcal{C}$ ?**

Comment: What is the different if we consider the dg-category?I am not family with dg-category.I can't understand your question.thanks